# jquery cannot deal with auto-generated DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code you can test it on http://jsfiddle.net/XBfMV/29/

html:

```
<div class="sam">div 1</div>
<div class="sam">div 2</div>
<div class="sam">div 3</div>
<div class="sam">div 4</div>
```

css:

```
.expanded{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
    background-color:yellow;
    min-height:50px;
}
```

javascript:

```
$('.sam').on('click',function(){   

    if ( $(this).hasClass('expanded') ){
        $(this).removeClass('expanded');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('expanded');

    }

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Im just test to write some divs after document ready
    var output = '<div class="sam">div 5</div>';
    $(output).insertAfter('.sam:last').fadeIn('slow');
    var output = '<div class="sam">div 6</div>';
    $(output).insertAfter('.sam:last').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

after running when click on the div1 , div2, div3 and div 4 it added/remove the .expanded class to the div but when clicking on the div5 and div6 which is generated by java and printed to the document it will not add/remove the class from them when I click into them.

any solutions?

Comment: `java !== javascript`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add selector to the `on` function.

Write:

```
$(document).on('click', '.sam', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
        $(this).removeClass('expanded');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('expanded');
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XBfMV/30/)

[Refer syntax.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$(document).on('click','.sam',function(){
```

because you are clicking in dynamic way.

Answer (score 2):

`.on()` only binds to elements already in existence, unless you delegate the actions.

Something like this will work:

```
$('body').on('click', '.sam', function() {
    // your code here
}
```